# How to change the color of the button when it is clicked in dhtmlx

Tags: dhtml, dhtmlx

can anybody help in adding an scolor i would be happy if u help me in doing

```
menu.setIconsPath("../common/imgs/");
menu.addNewSibling(null, "jan", "JAN");    //these jan to dec are button in menu bar
menu.addNewSibling("jan", "feb", "FEB");   //when it is clicked it must show in another 
menu.addNewSibling("feb", "mar", "MAR");   //color 
menu.addNewSibling("mar", "apr", "APR");
menu.addNewSibling("apr", "may", "MAY");
menu.addNewSibling("may", "jun", "JUN");
menu.addNewSibling("jun", "jul", "JUL");
menu.addNewSibling("jul", "aug", "AUG");
menu.addNewSibling("aug", "sep", "SEP");
menu.addNewSibling("sep", "oct", "OCT");
menu.addNewSibling("oct", "nov", "NOV");
menu.addNewSibling("nov", "dec", "DEC", false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next (not public) approach:

```
menu.attachEvent("onClick", function(id, zoneId, casState){
            menu.idPull[menu.idPrefix+id].style.backgroundColor = '#FFC000';
        });
```